# Getting Pointer from Parse.com record in to SQLite table

Tags: c#, sqlite, parse-platform, xamarin

Since a few days I've been using `Parse.com` to synchronize data to the cloud. I'm now writing all functions to fetch all data from the cloud and to synchronize it with a local `SQLite` database.

I fetch all the data from the cloud with a `ParseObject` like this:

```
 var taskQuery = from TaskTable in ParseObject.GetQuery("Task")
                           where TaskTable.Get<Boolean>("Deleted") == false
                           where TaskTable.Get<DateTime>("updatedAt") > SqliteSyncDate
                           select TaskTable;
 IEnumerable<ParseObject> tasks = await taskQuery.FindAsync();
```

After having it in the `ParseObject` I loop over it with a `foreach`but then I'm having problems. I have a table `Task` which has a field `UserId` that I defined as a `Pointer` to the table `Login`. I now have to store this `Pointer` in my SQLite database but I have no clue how to 'parse' and/or save it locally now.
My code:

```
//Loop over every record that is returned from Parse.com
        foreach (ParseObject task in tasks)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create new record to add to Task
                Tasks taskSqlite = new Tasks();
                taskSqlite.Id = task.Get<int>("Id");
                //This line fails! When I comment it out syncing works, otherwise it doesn't.
                taskSqlite.UserId = task.Get<int>("UserId");
                taskSqlite.Description = task.Get<string>("Description");
                taskname = task.Get<string>("Description");
                taskSqlite.Date = task.Get<DateTime?>("Date");
                taskSqlite.Done = task.Get<Boolean>("Done");
                taskSqlite.DoneBy = task.Get<string>("DoneBy");
                taskSqlite.Deleted = task.Get<Boolean>("Deleted");
                taskSqlite.LastModified = task.Get<DateTime?>("LastModified");

                //And finally insert the record in to the SQLite database.
                DATask.InsertTask(taskSqlite);
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("SYNC FAILURE - failed on table Task on the task: " + taskname);
            }
```

If I run this without the try catch I will get the following error:

```
03-31 16:37:52.676 I/MonoDroid( 4731): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
03-31 16:37:52.697 I/MonoDroid( 4731): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

**Update:** As pointed out I decided to also print the Exception. This is the Exception:

```
Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Value is not a convertible object:      
Parse.ParseObject to System.Int32
03-31 17:03:18.335 I/mono-stdout( 8270): SYNC FAILURE - failed on table Task
on the task:  Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Value is not a 
convertible object: Parse.ParseObject to System.Int32

[0:] SYNC FAILURE - failed on table Task on the task:  Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Value is not a convertible object:
Parse.ParseObject to System.Int32
at System.Convert.ToType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType,
IFormatProvider provider, Boolean try_target_to_type) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0 
at System.Convert.ChangeType (System.Object value, System.Type
conversionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Parse.ParseClient.ConvertTo[Int32] (System.Object value) [0x00000] in
<filename unknown>:0 
at Parse.ParseObject.Get[Int32] (System.String key) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0
```

I then created a `ParseRelation`. But how can I now get the UserId out of this?

```
ParseRelation<Parse.ParseObject> relatie = 
task.GetRelation<Parse.ParseObject>("UserId");
```

So how exactly should I convert it or save it into the SQLite database? Would this be the correct way to link records to eachother?

Comment: why don't you `catch (exception ex)` to see what the exception is?

Comment: Good point. Alright so its expecting a ParseRelation. I now have this but I have no clue how to get an item out of it (the UserId)

Comment: I would suggest you look [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html) at the API documentation for a clue as to how to extract userID from your `ParseObject`

Comment: There seems to be a getQuery option but I don't see any examples and neither about how I should query and/or get the value ouf then.. https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseRelation.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you got problems with the type int. Maybe try Int32 or something? If this doesn't help you could check the values in your database. Maybe the UserId isn't a numeric value that you can convert to int?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Turns out it is returned from the cloud database as a ParseObject which you then have to convert somehow..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply

```
taskSqlite.UserId = task.ObjectId;
```

Should do the trick